# In jmeter is there any option like "Submit a form from the previous request"?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, neoload

I just want to know in jmeter we have any feature like Submit a form from the previous sampler response like same as we have in loadrunner and neoload

Comment: Did you try building the data and posting it?

Comment: It is an open source product.  You could just extend the source for the capability you need.

Comment: @james, agreed, hoping in coming future we may have that feature.

Answer (score 1):

No JMeter has no such option (yet :-)) but it's a great idea:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59389

What you can do is use CSS/ JQuery Post Processor , extract inputs and inject them in the next sampler.

Comment: off course, currently i am doing same, thanks for your reply